# Impossible to plot OSM multipolygons in tmap and leaflet

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap, multipolygons, osmdata

I'm extracting data from OpenStreetMap using `osmdata`, and from the query I get a set of points, lines, polygons, and multipolygons. Somehow, when trying to plot multipolygons, leaflet and tmap do not find them, while using `plot(st_geometry(...))` works well.

Any ideas as to what is happening?

```r
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

nkpg_schools <- 
  opq(bbox = "Norrköping") %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "amenity", value = "school") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

plot(st_geometry(nkpg_schools$osm_multipolygons)) #Works well

tmap_mode("view")
tm_basemap("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas") +
  tm_shape(nkpg_schools$osm_multipolygons) +
  tm_polygons()
#Does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem! My first hunch was that the Norrköping schools multipolygon object was spatially invalid (which does happen with the OSM objects from time to time, unfortunately).

This seems not to be the case, see `sf::st_is_valid()` test results.

But! curiouser and curiouser: creating an intermediary object of schools made valid via `sf::st_make_valid()` causes the schools to behave themselves.

I confess I can not fully explain what's going there, but if it solves your problem - who are we to judge?

```r
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

nkpg_schools <- 
  opq(bbox = "Norrköping") %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "amenity", value = "school") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

st_is_valid(nkpg_schools$osm_multipolygons)
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 

intmd <- nkpg_schools$osm_multipolygons %>% 
  st_make_valid()

tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(intmd) +
  tm_polygons(col = "red") +
  tm_basemap("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas")
```

[image: Norrköping schools]

Comment: Wonderful! This is very weird indeed! Maybe worth a github issue. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: glad to be of service! It could be something about the order of polygons in multipolygon according to this standard or the other - OGC vs ESRI - or the famed water of life = buffer of distance zero that seems to heal many a stubborn shapefile... As long as it works :)